what log files in Linux to search for hardware errors
As an administrator what other log files, besides /var/log/messages, can you look through to see if there are any hardware errors or anomalies happening?
For example, you power on a Linux server at 5pm and let it sit idle overnight to 9am, where do you look in Linux to identify any hardware errors or anomalies have occurred?
I am interested in identifying only hardware problems, not software or kernel problems which would be rectified by a repartition of disk and a clean reinstall of Linux from iso.

For serious kernel messages (could overflow and disappear) only for the current boot:
dmesg --level=alert,crit,err,emerg,warn

or for all kernel messages, must be preserved as long as journald settings allow:
journalctl -k 

